# Dynamic addition of text view by clicking on button

Tags: android

If i click on a button on one layout it should add text view in another layout dynamically again if i click that button same procedure should get repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very easy to understand, do you mean activities instead of layouts? Or do you have a button in an activity and each time you press it, you want to have an additional text view on the same activity (for example below the button)?